# MYSQL return one value if two rows are equal

Tags: php, mysql

I got a MYSQL table looking like this

```
| id | User | Message |
_______________________
| 1  |John  | Hello Peter  
| 2  |Peter | Hello John
| 3  |Peter | How are you?
```

I need to find a Query like this:

Select the last row and get the username and Message (row 3) then substract by 1 (row 2) 
and if the username is the same as row 3 and row 2 then just return the Message from row 2.

Can someone help me?

Comment: If two rows are equal, or if two **consecutive** rows are equal ?

Comment: This is probably hard (or at least complicated) to implement as SQl query. Consider doing this using PHP *after* fetching

Comment: @Clément Malet - if two consecutive rows are equal

Comment: Is it if username and message are the same or just username?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry I wrote [THIS POST](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) to help with showing users how to correctly ask a question... thought i'd let you know incase you want to use it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are powering this through PHP, must you apply the criteria to the SQL query necessarily?

In PHP you would do something like this

```
<?php
$lastUser = '';
while (/* read next row */) {
    $user = $row['User'];
    $message = $row['Message'];
    if ($user == $lastUser) {
        $return = $message;
    } else {
        $return = "$user: $message";
    }
    $lastUser = $user;
    echo $return . '<br/>';
}
```

Where the while() clause would be dependent on your mysql adapter (iterating through some PDO results, or just a mysql_fetch_array()).

Answer (score -1):

It may work for you and always return the first user in the tables if more than one user are same. 
select id,User,Message from table group by User .